# how to parse json with alamofire and swiftjson?

Tags: xcode

I'm using swiftjson and alamofire  to parse the json.pls help fix my code.

[here the json array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zre4c.png)

Below are my code

```
    RestClient.sharedClient.getUserWallet(uid: uid!, token: token!) { (json, error) in
        print(json as Any)

        self.tableRows = json!["data"].count

        //ALL BELOW IS DONE BY SWIFTYJSON
        let jsonArray = json?["data"].array

        if jsonArray != nil {
            for object in jsonArray! {
                let walletCells: UserWalletCells = UserWalletCells(json: object)
                self.userWalletCells.append(walletCells)
            }
        }

class PackageList {

var id: Int?
var user_id: String?
var amount: Int?
var currency_id: Int?
var release_rate: Double?
var release_per_day: Int?
var release_date: String?
var end_date: String?
var total_release: Int?
var tier_id: Int?
var is_active: Int?
var created: String?
var modified: String?
var remainingdays: Int?


init(json: JSON){


    self.id = json["id"].intValue
    self.user_id = json["user_id"].stringValue
    self.amount = json["amount"].intValue
    self.currency_id = json["currency_id"].intValue
    self.release_rate = json["release_rate"].doubleValue
    self.release_per_day = json["release_per_day"].intValue
    self.release_date = json["release_date"].stringValue
    self.end_date = json["end_date"].stringValue
    self.total_release = json["total_release"].intValue
    self.tier_id = json["tier_id"].intValue
    self.is_active = json["is_active"].intValue
    self.created = json["created"].stringValue
    self.modified = json["modified"].stringValue
    self.remainingdays = json["remainingdays"].intValue

}
}
```

I'm using swiftjson and alamofire  to parse the json.pls help fix my code.

Comment: here is the json array. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zre4c.png

Comment: In Swift 4+ SwiftyJSON has become obsolete. Use the `Codable` protocol. Post the JSON as text rather than as image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will help you

```
       let json = JSON(response)
       let dictResult = json["data"].dictionaryValue
       let arrayValue = dictResult["apckage"].arrayValue
        var arrList = [PackageList]()
        for i in 0..<arrayValue.count{
            let packageList                        = PackageList()
            let dictRespose                      = arrayValue[i]
            packageList. id = dictRespose["id"].stringValue
            packageList. user_id = dictRespose["user_id"].stringValue
            packageList. amount = dictRespose["amount"].stringValue      
            arrList.append(packageList)
        }
        return arrTaxLis
```

Like this you put all your key. It may helps you. Thank you.